# Android state for keyboard and mouse focus

Tags: android

For edittext `android:state_focused` means keyboard focus or touch focus?

I am facing this problem, I have an edittext.I want to apply

> different background drawable and color for keyboard focus and touch
>   focus.

Also what is the difference of state_pressed and state_focused?

Comment: [this link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html) will help .

Answer (score 0):

> For edittext android:state_focused means keyboard focus or touch
>   focus?

It means, your `edittext` is focused. (Cursor will be in that edittext) Even if you didn't touch edittext, but the cursor is in that edittext , then it is focused.

If you want to apply different backgroud for different state, You can use

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/yourdrawable1" />
  <item android:state_enabled="true" android:drawable="@drawable/drawable2" />
  <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/drawable3" />
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/draw" />
</selector>
```

Here,

`state_pressed` --> when the edittext is touched (ACTION_DOWN)

You can combine those states to add more custom backgrounds. For ex:

```
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:state_enabled="true" android:drawable="@drawable/yourdrawable"/>
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:state_enabled="false" android:drawable="@drawable/yourdrawable"/>
```

Comment: ok I need to apply 2 different drawable for touch focus and keyboard focus(assume device is connected through external keyboard or chromebook kind of thing).

Comment: I think There is no state  for keyboard focus. You can do it programmatically

Comment: Can you please show me an example. Lets say I want to apply Drawable D1 on touch focus and Drawable D2 on keyboard focus(either tab/enter/arrow key press)